# Ruby UDPSocket throws ERRNO:ECONNRESET

Tags: ruby, sockets, udp

I am going to be developing a piece of software that acts like a "bridge": it will receive data on one port, transform that data somehow, and then send the data back out on another port to the same host.
I was planning on using the code sample below to test the bridge, but I don't currently have the bridge actually running yet.

My question is why the first call to `recv` trows `Errno::ECONNRESET`?
At the moment there is no remote UDP socket that will be sending data to port 6000, but since this is UDP we should not need to establish a connection anyways.
I just expected `recv` to block.

```
require 'socket'

s = UDPSocket.new
s.bind('localhost', 6000)
s.connect('localhost', 7000)

begin
  s.send('Bender, honey, we love you.', 0)
  puts s.recv(1024)
rescue Errno::ECONNRESET
  puts 'Shut up baby, I know it!'
end

puts 'The next recv will block like expected.'
s.recv(1024)
puts 'If you are reading this then there might be a problem...'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is an error on the socket `recv` will not block, but remove and return the error. In this case the packet probably was sent, but no receiver was set up at localhost:7000, so it got back an ICMP unreachable. So set the the socket error to `ECONNRESET`.